# Test for different time trend for different groups?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, panel-data

I have data (`y`) at different time points (`t`) for individuals (`i`) in 2 different groups (`g`).

I am trying to test if the coefficient of `t` on `y` is larger for individuals in group 2. In other words, is the time trend more steep for a given group?

How would I go about doing that?

EDIT: There is likely auto-correlation at the `i` level

````
| y | t | i | g |
|---|---|---|---|
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 2 |

```
````

Answer (score 0):

A regression model seems well suited to the task:

$$y = \alpha + \gamma \cdot \mathbf{I}(group=2) + \tau \cdot t + \delta \cdot \mathbf{I}(group=2) \times t + \varepsilon_i $$

This model includes an intercept, a dummy for belonging to group 2, a linear trend, and a trend-group 2 dummy interaction.

You will want to cluster the standard errors at the individual level. This will handle arbitrary autocorrelation of errors for each individual, but errors across individuals are assumed to be uncorrelated.

Then you will want to conduct a one-sided superiority test like $H0: \delta \le 0$ against $Ha: \delta >0$. This is because you have a directional hypothesis.

Here is an example with some pig data, where I add a small trend for all the pigs with even IDs:

```
. webuse pig, clear
(Longitudinal analysis of pig weights)

. xtset id week 

Panel variable: id (strongly balanced)
 Time variable: week, 1 to 9
         Delta: 1 unit

. gen group = mod(id,2) + 1

. replace weight = weight*(1 + .029*week/9) if group == 2
(216 real changes made)

. reg weight c.week##i.group, vce(cluster id)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =        432
                                                F(3, 47)          =    1537.07
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.9321
                                                Root MSE          =     4.4475

                                    (Std. err. adjusted for 48 clusters in id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
      weight | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        week |   6.179861   .1279902    48.28   0.000     5.922378    6.437344
     2.group |  -.1001493    .810877    -0.12   0.902    -1.731423    1.531125
             |
group#c.week |
          2  |   .3240612   .1876432     1.73   0.091    -.0534282    .7015506
             |
       _cons |   19.22106   .4775385    40.25   0.000     18.26038    20.18175
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The coefficient on group x time interaction is 0.324, which means that pigs from group 2 gain an additional 1/3 of kg compared to pigs from group one.

We want to test that $\delta_{group2 \times week} \le 0$ against the alternative that $\delta_{group2 \times week} > 0$. To do that, you can just take the two-sided p-value and divide by two. This gets us $\frac{0.091}{2}=0.0455$. This means that we can reject the null in favor of the alternative at the conventional level of significance. This data is consistent with group 2 pigs having a steeper trend.

If you want to calculate a one-sided 95% confidence interval, you can get that from a two-sided 90% CI because the overlap between two one-sided 95% CIs makes a two-sided 90% CI. In Stata, that's

```
lincom 2.group#c.week, level(90)

 ( 1)  2.group#c.week = 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      weight | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [90% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         (1) |   .3240612   .1876432     1.73   0.091     .0092097    .6389127
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So a one-sided 95%CI is $[.0092,+\infty)$, which excludes zero.